# In Angular Mat-Selection-List, how to load a selected list

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have load the list to my selection list. How do I set the selected value in my selection list after load?

Below is my html code

```
<div class="col-md">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Sub Issue Listbox</label>
      <mat-selection-list
        #IssueList
        style="max-height: 250px; overflow: auto"
        formControlName="issueId">
        <mat-list-option
          *ngFor="let item of subIssueList"
          [value]="item.issueId">
          {{ item.issueDesc }}
        </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
      <p>
        Options Selected:
        {{ IssueList.selectedOptions.selected.length }}
      </p>
      <button
        (click)="updateOqcReject()"
        mat-raised-button
        color="accent">
        Update Issue
      </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

As for my loaded list, this is the array.

[image]

As for my selected list, this is the array.
[image]

Apprieciate if someone there can guide me on how I can proceed on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the value of your control using the `setValue` method and send the `issueId`

In the method after you load your list you should call it.

Example:

```
this.form.get('issueId').setValue(selectedValue);
```

Where the `selectedValue` is the issueId that you want to select

Answer (score 1):

You can do with query the `MatSelectionList` and use `[selected]` input of `mat-selection-list`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'list-selection-example',
  styleUrls: ['list-selection-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'list-selection-example.html',
})
export class ListSelectionExample {
  typesOfShoes: any[] = [{id: 0, title: 'Boots'}, {id: 1, title: 'Clogs'}, {id: 2, title: 'Loafers'}, {id: 3, title: 'Moccasins'}, {id: 4, title: 'Sneakers'}];

  @ViewChild(MatSelectionList) list: MatSelectionList;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const mySelections = [{id: 1, title: 'Boots'}]
    /* Select your selections into MatSelectionList */
    mySelections.map((s) => this.list.selectedOptions.select(s.id as any))
  }
}
```

and in html

```
<mat-selection-list #shoes>
  <mat-list-option
    [selected]="shoes.selectedOptions.isSelected(shoe.id)"
    [value]="shoe.id"
    *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes"
  >
    {{shoe.title}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>

<p>Options selected: {{shoes.selectedOptions.selected.length}}</p>
```

you can test it in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-64muma?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-selection-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Flist-selection-example.html)